# How to disable Control-C in a WindowsXP Python console program?

Tags: python, windows-xp, console-application, copy-paste, control-c

I'd like to put my cmd.com window into a mode where Control-C does not generate a SIGINT signal to Python (ActiveState if it matters).

I know I can use the signal module to handle SIGINT. The problem is that handling SIGINT is too late; by the time it is handled, it has already interrupted a system call.

I'd like something equivalent to the *nix "raw" mode. Just let the input queue up and when it is safe for my application to read it, it will.

Maddeningly enough, msvcrt.getch() seems to return Control-C as a character. But that only works while the program is blocked by getch() itself. If I am in another system call (sleep, just to use an example), I get the SIGINT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the win32 API function [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016(VS.85).aspx) with NULL (0) as its first parameter and TRUE (1) as its second parameter. If you're already using pywin32, [win32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__SetConsoleCtrlHandler_meth.html) is fine for the purpose, otherwise ctypes should work, specifically via `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, 1)`/

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work (keeps sleep from being interrupted). Oddly enough, it causes the interactive prompt to exit and dump me back to the cmd.com window. That's not a problem for my application, just a curiosity.

Comment: I should say the behaviour in my previous comment was with ctypes, no pywin32, if that matters (oh, and I'm back in the stone age with Python24 :) ).

Comment: @dgou, always glad to help (if an answer decisively help solve your problem, remember to accept it: that's stack overflow etiquette!-).

Comment: Yes, it is very close. Interestingly, while Ctrl-C handling is disabled, the key event is completely swallowed. My primary goal is to prevent the interruption. It would have been nicer to get the character:
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, 1)
time.sleep(10) # during which I type ^C
msvcrt.get() # hangs waiting for a character.
# if I type A instead of ^C then getch() returns it without hanging.

Again, not a big deal, just this and the interactive prompt behaviour are curiosities. :)

Thanks again!